# Populating Queue Randomly in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsoperationqueue, arc4random

Right now I am setting up a queue based off of image names that works fine. It loops through images 0 through 13 and adds them to the queue.

```
loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSString *imageName;
for (int i=0; i < 13; i++) {
    imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

}
```

This works flawlessly; the queue is set up from cover_0.jpg through cover_13.jpg. I want to add a little randomness to it, however. If I just use an `arc4random()` I will undoubtedly get the same image added to the queue multiple times. Logically, how can I get `arc4random()` to be exclusive. Adding the chosen numbers to a string and then checking them against the current output, and if needed repeating the `arc4`, is redundant and inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:14];

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i]];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    int index = arc4random() % [tmpArray count];
    NSString *imageName = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [tmpArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
}

[tmpArray release];
```

And your code should not work flawlessly. You are leaking `imageName`.

Comment: Actually I'm not. `ARC` in iOS 5. Works like a charm ;)

Comment: Thats better. Though I don't know the details of ARC :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by first populating an array with the image names, and then randomly picking out values:

```
NSMutableArray * imageNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    NSString * iName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
    [imageNames addObject:iName];
}
while ([imageNames count] > 0) {
    int index = arc4random() % [imageNames count];
    NSString * iName = [imageNames objectAtIndex:index];
    [imageNames removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    // load image named iName here.
}
```